# difference between pixelcolor in Javascript canvas and PHP imagecolorat()

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing, canvas

I want to find the color of a pixel of jpeg image

in JavaScript , create a canvas from image and use getImageData method to gets color of pixel:

```
canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
```

and this function :

```
function getPixelColor( imagedata, x, y ) {
        var position = ( x + imagedata.width * y ) * 4, data = imagedata.data;
        return { r: data[ position ], g: data[ position + 1 ], b: data[ position + 2 ], a: data[ position + 3 ] };   
}
```

in php , these 3 line of code :

```
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath) ;

    $rgb = imagecolorat($img, '1', '1');

    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, $rgb);
```

when checks for equality of results, i found that they are not equal!

Sample result :

```
Canvas getImageData:

red : 238, green : 147, blue : 118

PHP imagecolorat:

red : 244, green : 145, blue : 113
```

anybody can suggest solutions to improve my results ?

thanks

Comment: arent't 0/0 and 1/1 two different pixel?

Comment: no, this method `getImageData()` returns an array of all pixels, with second function `getPixelColor()`  we gets the color of specific pixel.

Comment: So what parameters are you actually calling your `getPixelColor` function with?

Comment: called the `getPixelColor` with this parameters `var imgdata = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ); getPixelColor( imgdata, 1 , 1);`

Answer (score 1):

your looking at different pixels. 1,1 in phps case and 0,0 in javacripts